# Parse HTML in Enlive like in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, clojure, enlive

I am trying to get links from HTML in Clojure with Enlive. Can I get a list of all links from a page? Can I iterate over them?

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
# <html>
#  <head>
#   <title>
#    The Dormouse's story
#   </title>
#  </head>
#  <body>
#   <p class="title">
#    <b>
#     The Dormouse's story
#    </b>
#   </p>
#   <p class="story">
#    Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
#    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">
#     Elsie
#    </a>
#    ,
#    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">
#     Lacie
#    </a>
#    and
#    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link2">
#     Tillie
#    </a>
#    ; and they lived at the bottom of a well.
#   </p>
#   <p class="story">
#    ...
#   </p>
#  </body>
# </html>
```

```python
links = soup.find_all('a')
```

or

```python
links = soup('a')
```

How can I do this in Clojure with Enlive?

Comment: look at `enlive/select` and `[:a]`
https://github.com/cgrand/enlive#selector-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that would be very simple:

```lisp
(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as enlive])

(let [data (enlive/html-resource (java.net.URL. "https://www.stackoverflow.com"))
      all-refs (enlive/select data [:a])]
  (first all-refs))

;;=> {:tag :a, :attrs {:href "https://stackoverflow.com", :class "-logo js-gps-track", :data-gps-track "top_nav.click({is_current:true, location:1, destination:8})"}, :content ("\n                   " {:tag :span, :attrs {:class "-img"}, :content ("Stack Overflow")} "\n                ")}
```

the `all-refs` collection would contain all the links from page in enlive representation form.

```lisp
(let [data (enlive/html-resource (java.net.URL. "https://www.stackoverflow.com"))
      all-refs (enlive/select data [:a])]
  (map #(-> % :attrs :href) all-refs))
```

would for example collect all the `href` values from links

Answer (score 2):

First you need to ingest some HTML using Enlive's `html-resource` function. We'll grab news.google.com:

```
(defn fetch-url [url]
  (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. url)))
(def goog-news (fetch-url "https://news.google.com"))
```

To get all the `<a>` tags, use `select` function with a simple *selector* (the second argument):

```
(html/select goog-news [:a])
```

This will evaluate to a sequence of maps, one per `<a>` tag. Here's an example `<a>` tag map from today's news:

```
{:tag :a,
 :attrs {:class "nuEeue hzdq5d ME7ew",
         :target "_blank",
         :href "https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/01/first-black-panther-reviews",
         :jsname "NV4Anc"},
 :content ("The First Black Panther Reviews Are Here—and They're Ecstatic")}
```

To get the inner text of each `<a>`, you can `map` Enlive's `text` function over the results e.g.  `(map html/text *1)`. To get each `href`, you can `(map (comp :href :attrs) *1)`.